# Delete DB GLUE on AWS with python

Tags: python-3.x, aws-glue

How can i delete record in AWS GLUE in the database section with python AWS SDK? I have only the database name.

Comment: For any help, please provide all information, related to the question.  Having only the database name, one cannot help.  Do you have user credentials, the kind of database you are trying, is the database hosted on prem, or cloud (RDS?)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete a database from your Glue Catalog using Boto3 (python SDK for AWS), it goes like this:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('glue')
response = client.delete_database(Name='database-name')
```

The `delete_database` takes also an optional `CatalogId` parameter which defaults to your AWS account ID. Have a look into [Boto documentation for details](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.delete_database).